# Android memory leak - Activity and Views

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I wrote an android application, and tried to avoid memory leaks. For that, I used Eclipse Memory Analyzer. I got three problem suspect. Each is about Bitmap object with big size (two are 8.8MB, one is 5.8 MB).
I did in my code some tricks, and I'm not sure if they caused this:

- I set the activity as OnClickListener of some views.
- I created in runtime custom views, using getApplicationContext() as Context.
- I declared fields for holding views within the activity class.

Is one of this may cause to memory leak? Or maybe it is normal to have 8.8MB bitmap?

While getting into details, I saw that the first bitmap, for example, is holded by this:

```
byte[9216000] @ 0x42dda5b0 ..&...$...#...%...(...*...$... .........................z...t...t...y.........#...+...,...-...........(... .......$...*...&...%...%...&...'...'...#...........!...%...'...!... ..."...'...)...(...!.......!...*...-...,...+...'...$...&...&...$...........!...&....
 9,216,016 9,216,016 
\mBuffer android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x418f9028
.+mBitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable @ 0x420211b8
.|\mBGDrawable android.widget.LinearLayout @ 0x41fb5528
.|.\[0] android.view.View[12] @ 0x41fcbf60
.|..\mChildren android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x41fb4c90 
.|...\mContentParent com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow @ 0x4220f480
.|....+this$0 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView @ 0x41fd8bd0
.|....|+mView android.view.ViewRootImpl @ 0x4220f5c0
.|....||+this$0 android.view.ViewRootImpl$2 @ 0x42032ed8 Native Stack
.|....||+this$0 android.view.ViewRootImpl$AccessibilityInteractionConnectionManager @ 0x420330f0 »
.|....||\Total: 2 entries
.|....|+[1] android.view.View[5] @ 0x41932f18 »
```

Comment: I don't see any evidence of a memory leak in the small fragment you posted.  What makes you think that you have one?

Comment: @Simon It appeared under "problem suspected", and it has 8.8MB bitmap. I don't know if it is normal.

Comment: What size is the bitmap that you are loading?  How do you load it?  Do you scale it?

Comment: 18 images ~50KB each, total ~900KB, loaded by BitmapFactory from InputStream got from Assets, useing options.inSampleSize to scale.

Comment: The file size is not relevant.  By size, I mean resolution.  A 500x500 bitmap uses neqarly 2MB by default.